# How to convert a header row into array in cypress which returns the array

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cypress

I am iterating over the header of a ag-grid and want to save it a array

[image]

I can easily get text of each column in cypress through

```
cy.get("#myGrid").find('.ag-header-cell').invoke('text').then((text) => {
  var headArr:Array<String>;
  headArr = text.trim()
})
```

But this is not creating an array and also wanted to know how to return this array and assign it to a variable

Answer (score 2):

The first part `cy.get("#myGrid").find('.ag-header-cell')` will give you all the cells in the top (header) row.

If you `.invoke('text')` on that collection of elements, you get all the text in string with white-space between of varying lengths and it's difficult to know where to split into array elements.

Instead you can get the collection of elements as an array and invoke `text()` on each one via `.map()` function (not a Cypress command, it's built-in to Javascript).

Of course you probably know, Cypress uses `aliases` to store variables, so then just `.wrap()` that array of texts and create an alias variable.

```js
cy.get("#myGrid").find('.ag-header-cell')
  .then(headerElements => {

    const headerArray = Array.from(headerElements);
    const headerTexts = headerArray.map(header => header.invoke('text'))
    cy.wrap(headerTexts).as('headerTexts)
  })

...

// using my array alias variable
cy.get('@headerTexts').then(headerTexts => {
  ...       
})
```

Comment: You can condense the `.then()` block by just mapping the array of DOM elements directly.

Comment: Of course, but that makes the point of the answer less clear. And you gain nothing by doing so.